# Changing Windows 7 PATH avriable

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, python, path

I saw [this question and answer](https://superuser.com/questions/76219/changing-path-windows-7-without-restarting) but this is not working for me.
I am following Python tutorials. There is a [section](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html#invoking-the-interpreter) that requires me to change the path variable. I used the instructions in the command prompt on Windows-7. I used

```
echo %path%
```

to see the new PATH variable. It was correctly changed in the particular session of command prompt. But when I started a new session of command prompt and used

```
echo %path%
```

again to see the path variable it was unchanged.

So my question is how to change the PATH variable in WIndows-7 64-bit permanently?

Comment: To change your settings permanently, refer to the original question you pointed to. At the end he states "I'm currently changing variable from `Advanced Systems settings` > `Environment Variables`." That's how you do it.

Comment: @RandolphWest That worked. My mistake. I didn't read it completely. But is the Python documentation wrong about their commands?

Comment: Can't answer you there. I was responding to your very specific question on how to make environment changes permanent. Can I flag this question to close?

Comment: @RandolphWest Please wait a day or two. Maybe someone may answer the second part about copying from command prompt.

Comment: Please remove it from here and post that as a separate question.

Comment: @RandolphWest Ok I'll post that as a separate question. Vote it to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change PATH variable:
Go to `Advanced System Setting > Advanced Tab > Environment variable`, then find the PATH variable in the list provided
See here for details:
http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml
http://www.faqforge.com/windows/setting-the-path-environmental-variable-on-windows-7/
See here for some idea on how to do it through command line
[How can I permanently append an entry into the system's PATH variable, via command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/390701/how-can-i-permanently-append-an-entry-into-the-systems-path-variable-via-comma)
Simply changing or appending the PATH using the path command in cmd will only alter the path for that particular instance of cmd
To copy the contents of a cmd window, right click on it and click mark. Drag and select the content to copy using the mouse and paste it into your favorite word processor or notepad
If you want to send the output of path (or other cmd commands) to file, append "> aaa.txt" without the quotes after the cmd commands. aaa.txt is the file in which the output of the dos command will get written to and can be anything you want as long as it is a valid dos filename.