# Access denied on interactive (system) cmd

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I started interactive (system user) cmd to use some commands and I got back Access denied error. I could do it other ways, but I'm interested in how is it possible, that superuser-like account simply cannot access some location. Isn't it called SYSTEM user, because it can go everywhere where system is?

EDIT:
I'm trying to change ntldr to bootmgr. Both normal and admin version says Access denied, so I tried SYSTEM...

Comment: The short answer: Windows is stupid. Try right clicking on CMD then hitting run as administrator.

Comment: There is no problem running as admin. But I need SYSTEM rights (something even higher than admin (like linux SU))

Comment: How exactly did your create the CMD as System?  What are you getting Access Denied while trying to do exactly?  I ask because some things are prevented by UAC (and alike) regardless of which user you are.  Perhaps rethink/rewrite this question to be about the ACTUAL problem you're trying to solve (that you think you need System access for).  I suggest this because I've been doing Windows (use, program, repair, etc.) for a couple decades now and have never needed to do anything as "System" (directly).

Comment: `sc create testsvc binpath= "cmd /K start" type= own type= interact`
`sc start testsvc`

Comment: @Anagmate Pending edit queue approval, I tried to clarify your question according to what (I think) you wanted. Please revise if this is inaccurate. OTOH, my edits do match a weird scenario I've been having, so I hope my edit attracts some new answers.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 7 (and maybe even earlier) there's an account called TrustedInstaller, which has in some places higher privileges than the SYSTEM account (sorry, couldn't find the article I've read about it).

Another possibility is that somehow (probably manually) the permissions of the SYSTEM account removed from the object you're trying to get.

Anyway, what exactly are you trying to do that require SYSTEM privileges?

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these methods [Command prompt as SYSTEM user (Windows 7)](https://superuser.com/questions/614165/command-prompt-as-system-user-win-7) failing that as far as I know the actual admininstrator account itself(Not an account with admin rights, the default Windows admin account) has some extended rights http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/access-the-real-administrator-account-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 1):

psexec with the -s parameter can do the trick.

http://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip

```
psexec -i -d -s c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the OP is already running as the SYSTEM user, but getting "Access Denied" messages. Any ideas on how to fix that?