# Running Cmd as System User without psexec

Tags: windows-8.1, cmd.exe

Can I run cmd.exe as an interactive prompt without the psexec tool

I've tried scheduling it as a task, but it only runs as a background program. (conhost)  I verified that by checking the task manager as I enabled and disabled the task I scheduled.

Again, I'm looking to make it interactive essentially trying to make my computer think I am the system giving me unrestricted control.

The reason I can't use psexec right now is the sessions are being blocked by the network I'm currently using.  I'm going to try psexec again later, but was hoping for an alternative.

Using Windows 8.1  The cmd AT command doesn't work so tasks must be scheduled through the scheduler program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command prompt as SYSTEM user (Win 7)](http://superuser.com/questions/614165/command-prompt-as-system-user-win-7)

Comment: Accepted answer on dupe is an alternative to using PSExec.

Comment: That's not working, the start service command just keeps timing out