# Is it possible to have the PATH environment variable update without logging off?

Tags: windows-8.1, environment-variables

In Windows 8.1, if I change the Environment Variable for PATH under either System or User and open a command prompt and execute `path`, whatever I appended to PATH is not shown unless I sign out of my current Windows session and log back on.

Is there anyway to have the PATH reflect my change without the log in/log out?

This question is different to the one asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/76219) as that one notes that logging back on and/or opening a new command prompt solves the problem.  That answer does not answer this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change the PATH environmental variable in Windows 7 without restarting?](http://superuser.com/questions/76219/can-i-change-the-path-environmental-variable-in-windows-7-without-restarting)

Comment: @Techie007 that question recommends relogging, this question is about not relogging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any changes to `PATH` should update automatically. You usually have to exit and re-launch any open programs though.

You can also try killing `explorer.exe` and re-launching it to see if that works for you.

Comment: The part of your answer that helped the most was "re-launch any open programs".  I actually open cmd via executor (a launch app).  After asking this question, I found that opening cmd via Run did show the updated PATH.  I just did another test now, and after changing the PATH but then relaunching executor and opening cmd the PATH was updated.  Thanks so much.